# Find the last child element in JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file structured like that :

```
"FAMILY": {
        "1": {
            "ANNA": {
                "name": "ANNA X",
                "alive": true,
                "children": {
                    "MAX": {
                        "name": "MAX X",
                        "alive": false,
                        "children": {}
                    },
                    "TOM": {
                        "name": "TOM X",
                        "children": {
                            "TOM JR": {
                            "name": "MAX X",
                            "alive": true,
                            "children": {...}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "2":...
}
```

I'd like to find the last child (of children data) who is alive. We don't know the number of family member so I can't do one loop per people. 
How can I do that? Loop all Anna's family and find the last child alives.

Thanks.

Comment: What if both MAX and TOM both got 3 grandchildren each. Do you want them all?

Comment: Only one Anna's child can have children. This is the same behavior for other family members.

Comment: Are you familiar with tree data structure? You're basically looking for the depth of the tree, with a small modification where you check if the person is alive when you reach a leaf.

Comment: Not really. Yes the idea is to obtain the last active leaf of current tree. I tried to do that but I was stuck in the last child.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursion to iterate in every node there is and calculate level depth. You also need a variable to hold the node with deepest level. When the recursion is over, you return the variable. Look for recursion and bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should be help, here i have considered your object is in `obj` variable

```
var last_member =null;
function getLastChildren(obj)
{
    for(i in obj)
    {
        if(typeof obj[i].children !== "undefined")
        {
            getLastChildren(obj[i].children);
        }
        else if(typeof obj[i].alive !== "undefined" && obj[i].alive)
        {
            last_member=obj[i];
        }
    }
}
getLastChildren(obj.FAMILY);
console.log(last_member);
```

**Another solution for Get Last member of deepest level**

```
var last_member =null;
var deep_level=0;
function getLastChildren(obj, current_level)
{
    for(i in obj)
    {
        if(typeof obj[i].children !== "undefined")
        {
            getLastChildren(obj[i].children, current_level+1);
        }
        else if(typeof obj[i].alive !== "undefined" && obj[i].alive current_level>=deep_level)
        {
            last_member=obj[i];
            deep_level=current_level;
        }
    }
}
getLastChildren(obj.FAMILY,1);
console.log(last_member);
```

Thanks

Comment: it only takes the first children. we need to get into the children in the deepest level.

Comment: ahh, yes let me modify answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. yeah that's what I already tried but it loops only the first child. So I can't access to the other children.

Comment: I have modified for deep level... please check

Comment: added another solution for Get Last member of deepest level.